# Azure Table Client ListTablesSegmented

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

When I use `CloudTableClient.ListTableSegmented` to retrieve the tables, I get a weird behaviour when I specify the max number of results to receive. I'm using version 2.0.3 of WindowsAzure.Storage.

[This help reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj731923.aspx) says if I use 0 as maxResults, `ListTablesSegmented` should return the maximum possible number of results, up to 5000. When I use 0 as input the method throws an exception, saying the value should be positive greater than zero, and if I use 4999 or 5000 I get a `StorageException` with InvalidInput as error code. Everything runs smooth if I use for example 1000, or other values.

Am I doing anything wrong or anyone knows if this is a known bug?
I didn't find it amongst [the known issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/10/updated-known-issues-for-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the documentation. A single call to table service can return a maximum of 1000 entities (or tables). Please see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179405.aspx. 5000 is applicable to blob storage (listing containers and blobs) and queues (listing queues).